# How can I mimic the iOS settings page layout?

Tags: ios

I'm developing an app and I want to make it look like the settings page on iOS:

[image]

I already have this:

[image]

But as you can see I couldn't replicate the gray background and the section titles.

How can I do that? Create that gray background and add a space like in this image:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: It's a grouped style table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch your tableview style from `plain` to `grouped`.

[image]

Then just use the below code to set your section titles just as you usually would, they will appear the same as the settings app:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "some section title"
}
```